# Problems with changing variable in if-else statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a problem with this snippet of code. Everything is wrapped inside a $(document).ready function. My console log is down below, for some reason it keeps going into the else part of the statement even if the aoc variable is false. I have also tried with else if (aoc = true), but same thing happens.

```
    var aoc = false;

$("#aocBtn").click(function(e) {
    console.log(aoc);
    if (aoc = false) {
        $(this).removeClass("btn-outline-primary").addClass("btn-primary");
        aoc = true;
        console.log("Aoc was false and is now: "+aoc);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-outline-primary");
        aoc = false;
        console.log("Aoc was true and is now: "+aoc);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[image]

Comment: Use `===`  or `==` for comparisons instead of `=` i.e. `aoc == false`

Comment: `=` is for assignment. Use `==` or `===` for comparisons

Comment: `if (aoc = false) {` is assigninment

Comment: Always remember: `=`: Assigning value, `==`: Comparing values, `===`: Comparing values including its datatype

Comment: Ah sorry guys, must've been staring myself blind!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(aoc == false)
```

Your if statement is an assignment, not a condition, hence it is assigning false to the variable aoc. Replace with the "==" operator, which is the conditional check, and your code should run fine.

Also, had you written

```
if(aoc = true)
```

Instead of false, then only the "if" part would have worked at all times.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
aoc ? $(this).removeClass("btn-outline-primary").addClass("btn-primary") : $(this).removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-outline-primary");
aoc = !aoc;
```